# plot 3D using python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I try to use python plotting a 3D graph using the code below. It seems can not plot (lon, lat, lev, value) four dimensions in one figure. the value represents the `Zano_Tave_QV` variable.
Thanks in advance.

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np

from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm

#%matplotlib inline
my_file = 'Downloads/Zano_Tave_QV.nc'
fh = Dataset(my_file, mode='r')
#print(fh.variables)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
X = fh.variables['lat'][:]
Y = fh.variables['lon'][:]
Z = fh.variables['lev'][:]

#F = H.reshape(len(X),len(Y))
cset = ax.contourf(X, Y, Z, cmp=cm.coolwarm)
print(H)
ax.clabel(xset, fontsize=9, inline=1)

plt.show()
```

The `Zano_Tave_QV.nc` file is in this link https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IOmOkkvv1qyx-y1FRS6FKAJLnTt7UZ1s:

The traceback information is

```
TypeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-fec6b75cf787> in <module>()
     18 
     19 #F = H.reshape(len(X),len(Y))
---> 20 cset = ax.contourf(X, Y, Z, cmp=cm.coolwarm)
     21 print(H)
     22 ax.clabel(xset, fontsize=9, inline=1)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py in contourf(self, X, Y, Z, *args, **kwargs)
   2221 
   2222         jX, jY, jZ = art3d.rotate_axes(X, Y, Z, zdir)
-> 2223         cset = super(Axes3D, self).contourf(jX, jY, jZ, *args, **kwargs)
   2224         self.add_contourf_set(cset, zdir, offset)
   2225 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in inner(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1853                         "the Matplotlib list!)" % (label_namer, func.__name__),
   1854                         RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2)
-> 1855             return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1856 
   1857         inner.__doc__ = _add_data_doc(inner.__doc__,

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py in contourf(self, *args, **kwargs)
   6179             self.cla()
   6180         kwargs['filled'] = True
-> 6181         contours = mcontour.QuadContourSet(self, *args, **kwargs)
   6182         self.autoscale_view()
   6183         return contours

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/contour.py in __init__(self, ax, *args, **kwargs)
    844         self._transform = kwargs.pop('transform', None)
    845 
--> 846         kwargs = self._process_args(*args, **kwargs)
    847         self._process_levels()
    848 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/contour.py in _process_args(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1414                 self._corner_mask = mpl.rcParams['contour.corner_mask']
   1415 
-> 1416             x, y, z = self._contour_args(args, kwargs)
   1417 
   1418             _mask = ma.getmask(z)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/contour.py in _contour_args(self, args, kwargs)
   1472             args = args[1:]
   1473         elif Nargs <= 4:
-> 1474             x, y, z = self._check_xyz(args[:3], kwargs)
   1475             args = args[3:]
   1476         else:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/contour.py in _check_xyz(self, args, kwargs)
   1506 
   1507         if z.ndim != 2:
-> 1508             raise TypeError("Input z must be a 2D array.")
   1509         elif z.shape[0] < 2 or z.shape[1] < 2:
   1510             raise TypeError("Input z must be at least a 2x2 array.")

TypeError: Input z must be a 2D array.
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback and consider cutting this down to an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @roganjosh  Is this not clear?

Comment: in a 3d contourf, you first need a mesh grid of x and y points using `np.meshgrid`. Lets says you have a 2d square grid of 10x10 = 100 points. It means for each x value you have 10 y values and vice versa. Now at each of these 100 points (a pair of x and y) you have a z value. That being said, your Z should be a 10x10 matrix. Now you can print the shape of X, Y and Z and see that is not the case currently and hence the error. Check [this](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/04.04-density-and-contour-plots.html) page for a sample on how to use `contourf`

Comment: It's good practice to add resources that you have used for research in order to solve your problem.

Comment: @lukas_o  I have added the file used in the code.